# How can I sync a particular music folder to iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I want to sync the music folder on my system with iPhone. The folder does not contain any sub folders and only contains mp3 files. I want my iPhone music library to get synced with this particular folder like if I add/delete any song the change should be reflected on my iPhone when I sync it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like an ideal task for iTunes & a single Playlist sync.

- Launch iTunes, connect iPhone then select it from the top menu
- Click Music in the Settings section, not 'On my Device'
- Set 'Selected Playlists...'
- Choose a single playlist to sync.

[image]